# Random #NAME error only while running macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have this workbook that links to another workbook with a simple formula using named ranges.  However, there are multiple sheets in this other workbook that uses the same named range.  This is one of the formulas

```
='C:\Account\Onshore'!Account_Balance_USD/'C:\Account\Combined'!Account_Balance_USD
```

When I open the workbook, this formula will give me a %.  But sometimes, while running a macro, the cell becomes #NAME and then I have to press debug, go to this cell and hit enter for it to give me a percentage again.  I'm wondering why it does that?

Comment: In Excel, those names will evaluate, meaning the application will find the value associated with that name. In VBA, a string is a string, unless otherwise specified. If you want to use a named range, use `Range("Name")` or search through the `Workbook.Names` collection.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the issue, are you saying the macro doesn't interact with these cells but they are changing to #NAME during execution?

Comment: The macro just takes the value of the cell and uses it in some small calculations.  But when it does that, the cell goes from having a value to becoming #NAME.  And its only sometimes.

Comment: You should add the code to your question. It might be an issue that is unintentionally caused by erroneous code, or perhaps something that could be added to prevent this interaction.

Comment: I recall a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394871/running-a-macro-that-opens-another-workbooks-gives-a-name-error-in-cells-that)

Comment: Does your "problematic" code use `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`?

Answer (score 1):

For all those wondering what happened to this post, like Toddleson said, I had a named range that was being used BUT it was actually connected to a different workbook that was open most of the time but closed sometimes which triggered the "#NAME".  It was incorrectly linked since this workbook ALSO had the same named range for itself which I corrected by getting rid of the named range linked to the other workbook.